# Why can’t back ticks be used in JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript

Why are back ticks for object properties invalid syntax? For example, this is valid:

```js
const test = {
  "test1": "test2"
}
```

So why can’t it have back ticks instead?

```js
const test = {
  `test1`: "test2"
}
//throws unexpected token error
```

It would be really helpful if back ticks could be used like this, but we can’t. Is there a simple alternative, or maybe this works in some browsers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to put it into brackets like this because it's evaluated at runtime.

```
const test = {
  [`test1`]: "test2"
}
```

As @Amadan pointed out in the comment, you can use any expression as a property key by putting it into brackets.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this:

```
const key = `test1`
const test = { [key]: 'test2' }
```